# laravel using twitter bootstrap and datepicker

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, datepicker

I am trying to render a datepicker in the form created by laravel tags. So far, nothing else is showing except a regular text field.

I've used [this](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter) for the datepicker. And I did the below in the form:

```
<p>{{ Form::text('dob', '', array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => 'تاريخ الميلاد', 'data-datepicker' => 'datepicker')) }}</p>
```

Nonetheless, I am only getting this:[image]

What is the recommendation here? I also added the css and js to the header so all should be in place.

Thanks,

Update: calling datepicker js function in the footer.blade.php where all other calls are:

```
{{ HTML::script('/public/assets/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('/public/assets/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js') }}

<script>
    $('.datepicker').datepicker()
</script>
```

This still didn't change anything.

Comment: Have you called the datepicker via javascript? $('.datepicker').datepicker()

Comment: Didn't make an explicit call. Where should it be added? only $('.datepicker').datepicker() will do?

Comment: This should be added to your javascript add the html class datepicker to your component and then where ever your javascript for your page is just add $('.datepicker').datepicker(). and it should work.

Comment: I did that and it didn't work...Updating the question to include it

Comment: add the datepicker class to the class attribute of your text field.

Comment: I already have this in my form field declaration: 'data-datepicker' => 'datepicker'. This is not what you referring to ?

Comment: No change 'class' => 'form-control' to 'class' => 'form-control datepicker' and see if it works then.

Comment: Nope it doesn't. Tried it already. array('class' => 'form-control datepicker'

Answer (score 0):

Use an id to initialize the datepicker

```
{!! Form::input('date', 'dob', date('d-m-Y'), ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'dob', 'data-date-format' => "dd-mm-yyyy"]) !!}
```

and use this javascript

```
$('#dob').datepicker();
```